# Select option values loaded with AJAX call, shows error illegal choice has been detected

Tags: 6, ajax

I have a select field in my form named country. on change country i need to load values in state. I already placed the field for listing state, only want to load the values from ajax. In same way I need to add city field also. whenever I submit form it shows state (field loaded by ajax) is ' An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator'. How can I update the new option values of field state which I have loaded from ajax call to the drupal form. How to clear the particular field cache data?
i will provide a code sample soon .

```
$('#edit-field-p-location-value').change(function(){
        form_build_id = $('input[name=form_build_id]').val();
        locationval = $(this).val();
        var url = window.location.href;
        var arr = url.split("/");
        var result = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];
        if(locationval!= ''){
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url: result+"/gasf/getIPSecZone/"+locationval,
                data:{datacenter:locationval},
                success : function(data){
                    //$('#edit-field-p-ipseczone-value-wrapper').html(data);
                    $('#edit-field-p-ipseczone-value').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the in-build [Drupal AJAX](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax) functions rather than writing your own. The [Examples for Developers](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module has detailed examples you can copy.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can add to select box

```
'#validated' => 'true'
```

in your form or in form_alter. 
But i would like to suggest you, use Drupal AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Form Api in drupal 7 has some attributes like `["#ajax"]` etc which needs to be used for this, not the jquery way as you posted.

Try implementing the below logic, you will need to change the sql queries etc for fetching country/city etc

```
    function mymodule_country_state_city($form, & $form_state, $no_js_use = FALSE) {
        $options_first = _profile_myprofile_get_first_dropdown_options();
        if (isset($form_state['values']['state_of_residence'])) {
            $selected = isset($form_state['values']['country_of_residence']) ? $form_state['values']['country_of_residence'] : key($options_first);
        } else if ($profile_country_residence_country_id > 0) {
            $selected = $profile_country_residence_country_id; 
            // $profile_country_residence_country_id is the default value 
        }
        //$options_second = _ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($selected);

        $form['country_of_residence'] = array(
            '#type' = > 'select',
            '#title' = > 'Country of Residence',
            '#options' = > $options_first,
            '#default_value' = > $selected,
            '#required' = > TRUE,
        // Bind an ajax callback to the change event (which is the default for the
        // select form type) of the first dropdown. It will replace the second
        // dropdown when rebuilt
        '#ajax' = > array(
        // When 'event' occurs, Drupal will perform an ajax request in the
        // background. Usually the default value is sufficient (eg. change for
        // select elements), but valid values include any jQuery event,
        // most notably 'mousedown', 'blur', and 'submit'.
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' = > 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback',
            'wrapper' = > 'dropdown-second-replace', ), );
        if (isset(
        $form_state['values']['state_of_residence'])) {
            $selected_state = isset($form_state['values']['state_of_residence']) ? $form_state['values']['state_of_residence'] : key($options);
        } else if ($profile_country_residence_state_id > 0) {
            $selected_state = $profile_country_residence_state_id;
        } else {
            $selected_state = 0; // 0 is default value
        }

        $form['state_of_residence'] = array(
            '#type' = > 'select',
            '#title' = > 'State of Residence',
            '#required' = > TRUE,
        // The entire enclosing div created here gets replaced when country_of_residence
        // is changed.
            '#prefix' = > '<div id="dropdown-second-replace">',
            '#suffix' = > '</div>',
        //    // when the form is rebuilt during ajax processing, the $selected variable
        //    // will now have the new value and so the options will change
            '#options' = > _ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($selected),
            '#default_value' = > $selected_state,
            '#ajax' = > array(
        // When 'event' occurs, Drupal will perform an ajax request in the
        // background. Usually the default value is sufficient (eg. change for
        // select elements), but valid values include any jQuery event,
        // most notably 'mousedown', 'blur', and 'submit'.
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' = > 'ajax_example_dependent_dropdown1_callback',
            'wrapper' = > 'dropdown-third-replace', ), );

        $form['city_of_residence'] = array(
            '#type' = > 'select',
            '#title' = > 'City of Residence',
            '#required' = > TRUE,
        //    // The entire enclosing div created here gets replaced when country_of_residence
        //    // is changed.
            '#prefix' = > '<div id="dropdown-third-replace">',
            '#suffix' = > '</div>',
        //    // when the form is rebuilt during ajax processing, the $selected variable
        //    // will now have the new value and so the options will change
            '#options' = > _ajax_example_get_third_dropdown_options($selected_state),
            '#default_value' = > $profile_country_residence_city_id, );
        return $form;
    }

    function ajax_example_dependent_dropdown_callback($form, $form_state) {
        $commands = array();
        $commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#dropdown-second-replace", render($form['state_of_residence']));
        $commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#dropdown-third-replace", render($form['city_of_residence']));
        return array('#type' = > 'ajax', '#commands' = > $commands);
        //return $form['state_of_residence'];
    }

    function ajax_example_dependent_dropdown1_callback($form, $form_state) {
        return $form['city_of_residence'];
    }
    /**
     * Helper function to populate the first dropdown. This would normally be
     * pulling data from the database.
     *
     * @return array of options
     */
    function _profile_myprofile_get_first_dropdown_options() {
        $country_query_result1 = db_query("SELECT country_id,country_name FROM country ORDER BY country_name ASC");
        $country_array = array();
        foreach($country_query_result1 as $row1) {
            $country_array[$row1 - > country_id] = $row1 - > country_name;
        }
        return $country_array;
    }
    /**
     * Helper function to populate the second dropdown. This would normally be
     * pulling data from the database.
     *
     * @param key. This will determine which set of options is returned.
     *
     * @return array of options
     */
    function _ajax_example_get_second_dropdown_options($key = '') {
        ///$i = 1;
        $options = array();
        $country_query_result1 = db_query("SELECT country_id FROM country ORDER BY country_id ASC");

        foreach($country_query_result1 as $row1) {
            $country_id = $row1 - > country_id;
            //    $country_id = $key;

            $state_query_result2 = db_query("SELECT state_id,state_name FROM state WHERE country_id = :country_id", array(':country_id' = > $country_id));
            $state_array = array();
            $state_array[0] = '-- Select State --';
            foreach($state_query_result2 as $row2) {
                $state_array[$row2 - > state_id] = $row2 - > state_name;
            }
            $options[$country_id] = $state_array;
        }
        if (isset($options[$key])) {
            return $options[$key];
        } else {
            $options1 = array('0' = > '-- Select State --');
            return $options1;
        }
    }

    function
     _ajax_example_get_third_dropdown_options($key = '') {
        ///$i = 1;
        $options_second = array();
        $country_query_result1 = db_query("SELECT country_id FROM country ORDER BY country_id ASC");
        $state_array1 = array();
        foreach($country_query_result1 as $row1) {
            $country_id = $row1 - > country_id;

            $state_query_result2 = db_query("SELECT state_id FROM state WHERE country_id = :country_id", array(':country_id' = > $country_id));
            $state_array = array();
            foreach($state_query_result2 as $row2) {
                $state_id = $row2 - > state_id;
                $state_query_result3 = db_query("SELECT city_id,city_name FROM city WHERE state_id = :state_id", array(':state_id' = > $state_id));
                $state_array3 = array();
                $state_array3[0] = '-- Select City --';
                foreach($state_query_result3 as $row3) {
                    $state_array3[$row3 - > city_id] = $row3 - > city_name;
                }
                $options_second[$state_id] = $state_array3;
            }
        }


        if (isset($options_second[$key])) {
            return $options_second[$key];
        } else {
            $options1 = array('0' = > '-- Select City --');
            return $options1;
        }
    }
```

Some useful links: http://w3shaman.com/article/creating-ajax-dropdown-drupal-7 
http://taggartjensen.com/code-snip/drupal-7-custom-form-ajex-use-custom-table